# How can I ensure either one specific task, or the rest, can run at a time with asyncio?

Tags: python, mutex, python-asyncio

I have a system that processes events. Every now and then a configuration change may happen that means events must stop being processed while the system is reconfigured. For example (simplified and abstracted):

```py
class System:
    # this will be running multiple times concurrently
    async def process_events(self, event):
        # this line must not be run while `reconfigure_event_processing` is running
        handler = await lookup_event_handler(self.handler_lookup_config, event)

        await handler.handle_event(event)

    async def reconfigure_event_processing(self, config):
        # this code must wait until nothing is using `lookup_event_processing_configuration`
        self.handler_lookup_config = config
```

The documentation of [`asyncio` synchronisation primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) is quite confusing to me, so I want to know which of them, if any, solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this a long time later, I've realised that what I really needed was what is called a **[read-write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)**. For this you should just use a tried and tested library, such as [`aiorwlock`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiorwlock).

From Wikipedia:

> An RW lock allows concurrent access for read-only operations, while write operations require exclusive access. This means that multiple threads can read the data in parallel but an exclusive lock is needed for writing or modifying data. When a writer is writing the data, all other writers or readers will be blocked until the writer is finished writing

Example usage is as follows:

```py
from aiorwlock import RWLock

class System:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = RWLock()

    async def process_events(self, event):
        async with self.lock.reader_lock:
            handler = await lookup_event_handler(self.handler_lookup_config, event)

        await handler.handle_event(event)

    async def reconfigure_event_processing(self, config):
        async with self.lock.writer_lock:
            self.handler_lookup_config = config
```

---

My original solution can be seen [in the revision history of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63661742/1), but I'd strongly recommend simply using an existing library instead.

Answer (score 2):

With multiple instances of `process_events` running in parallel, handling the synchronization with `reconfigure_event_processing` depends on what the code looks like that you haven't shown in your question: that is, how are you spawning `process_events` tasks?

Here's a short example I put together that uses an `asyncio.Condition` object to coordinate things. This is actually a runnable example:

```
import asyncio
import random

from itertools import count


class System(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.condition = asyncio.Condition()
        self.flag = False

    async def process_events(self, event):
        print('start process event', event)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        print('end process event', event)

    async def reconfigure_event_processing(self, config):
        self.flag = True

        async with self.condition:
            await self.condition.wait()
            print('start reconfigure')
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            print('end reconfigure')
            self.flag = False
            self.condition.notify()

    async def mainloop(self):
        tasks = set()
        for i in count():
            if self.flag:
                print('wait for tasks to complete')
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
                tasks = pending
                print('done waiting for tasks')
                async with self.condition:
                    self.condition.notify()
                    await self.condition.wait()

            tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(self.process_events(i)))
            if len(tasks) >= 4:
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
                    tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                tasks = pending

    async def reconfigure(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
            await self.reconfigure_event_processing('foo')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    system = System()
    # run mainloop() and reconfigure() concurrently forever
    asyncio.run(asyncio.gather([system.mainloop(), system.reconfigure()]))
```

The logic here is essentially:

1. `reconfigure_event_processing` raises a flag when it needs to run, and then waits on `self.condition`.
2. When the main loop sees the flag, it waits for all running tasks to complete and then notifies the condition, which causes `reconfigure_event_processing` to run.
3. Meanwhile, the main loop itself waits on the condition.
4. When `reconfigure_event_processing` is done, it notifies the condition and unsets the flag.

If you run this, you'll see that (a) all running tasks complete before you see the `start reconfigure` output, and (b) no more tasks are started until you see the `end reconfigure` output.

Comment: That was exactly my problem: multiple `process_events` will be running concurrently.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the main application loop (`mainloop()`) so/and it's not quite what I'm looking for. Thanks very much though, you pointed me in the right direction and helped me understand the "synchronisation primitives" better. I will post my solution now.